# Showing a dialog after the main window appears

Tags: c#, wpf, dialog

I have found several similar questions, but nothing that fits perfectly.

I want my main window to show up first, and if the application can't find an application configuration file I want it to pop up a dialog box to get some necessary values from the user.

If I do anything in App.xaml etc - then obviously the main window won't be open, the same goes for if I put it in my main window's `OnInitialized`. If I put it in `OnActivated`, it seems to work, but when I close the dialog or somehow click on the main window it pops up another copy of the dialog. I could put a bool in my main window that indicates whether the dialog box is open already, but that just doesn't seem optimal or the best way of doing things.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Loaded`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.loaded.aspx) instead.

Comment: I was overriding `OnInitialized` etc, but adding an event handler to `Load` worked great. The main problem was not setting the dialog's `.Owner`. That took care of making sure it only opened once...

Comment: What- `Loaded` only occurs once for windows, unlike `Activated` which is fired when the window gets focus, there should never be more than one instance, so it should work on its own just fine.

Comment: But the user should be able to open it manually later on - but I'm giving you the points. I just had to wait until the minimum time had elapsed.